# The way to use mouse over SSH on Mac OSX?

Tags: mac-osx

Does the `gpm` have a client on Mac OSX?

update 1:

Could the X11 on Mac OSX be help?

Update 2:

I would like to use mouse on Gentoo server, via a terminal environment on Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think X11 is the way to go here. Make sure that your Gentoo install will allow remote X sessions (or just go ahead and try it), open X11 on the Mac (from Utilities, or install it from the OS X CD or via http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki ). Then open a standard Terminal session (not the X11 session) and do "ssh -X username@gentooserver". Once you have logged in, you should be able to start X-Windows applications from the regular Terminal session and they will start in the OS X X-Windows server.

As I'm usually a SUSE user, I tend to use a lot of "yast2" this way.

Comment: You can skip the "open X11 on the Mac" — since OS X 10.5 it will start automatically when you connect an X application within that "ssh -X".

Answer (score 1):

Total shot in the dark, but perhaps piping synergy through an ssh tunnel will help. Know what I'm suggesting here? Need more details?

Comment: Yes, please let me know your suggestions.

Comment: Synergy is a tool for letting you share a single keyboard & mouse to control pretty much as many machines as you like. It works across Operating Systems (Linux, Windows, Mac OS) and is fairly easy to setup. In short one machine actually has a keyboard/mouse and it's configured as a server to share them with other machines - which happens when you move your mouse to a screen boundry - the input will then be redirected to the appropriate machine.

You can apply ssh with synergy to secure your keyboard/mouse traffic. Syngery Website: http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/

Want more info?

Answer (score 1):

We need some clarification, Are you connecting to the OS X computer or from it? What is your goal? Do you just want to be able to use a mouse in a terminal environment or do you want to remotely control another computer?

Comment: Hi, question updated.

Comment: I was able to replicate the answer on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918758/how-to-delete-highlighted-text-in-a-ssh-terminal

But I couldn't get it to work in the native ssh client on my Mac. You might want to try using a different SSH client that might better support passing the mouse movements.

Answer (score 1):

VNC.

You can enable VNC access (built-in to OSX) and then just use a VNC Client on the linux desktop.

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers related to X11 forwarding, VNC, etc are all well and good when connecting to a remote system which has X and/or X programs installed. If you're connecting to a server with NO GUI components the real question of the OP still hasn't been answered.

It's the MAC terminal, not the ssh client, which messes with the mouse-passing to ssh sessions. By starting X11 (from utilities as stated by Johnnie) and xterm, running the native MAC SSH client from xterm instead of  mac terminal, nano -m on the remote system can process the mouse clicks. There may be other terminals for MAC which will behave this way without having to start x11, and there may be a setting which I haven't been able to find which allows the MAC terminal to behave this way. This doesn't require X on the remote system, and works for AT LEAST vi(m) and nano.

Comment: As of OS X El Capitan 10.11, Terminal supports Mouse Reporting.